# Rails backend 500 errors for old assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, ruby-on-rails-5

When I deploy a new version on my server with new asset versions, I often see some 500 errors reported by amazon. In the logs, I see that those request seem to try to fetch old versions of assets (old asset digest)

> F, [2016-09-12T22:47:46.657377 #6663] FATAL -- : [1a552b90-e121-4817-8d22-28d02677c12a] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-3d5482837991d4fb95e72bd2c8ea9c08b07b349115db14016c71d86b5e295fc2.js"):

I am actually quite disturbed when I see logs like this, as I'm not really sure what's happening on the client side : does the browser not render any JS/CSS at all, or does it poll the server again to get the new assets ?? Since I have never witnessed html-only page rendering after server updates, I assume everything is actually okay, but is it ?.

I'm using so many developer tools, that are fiddling with cache options, and I'm thinking maybe some users that browse without those things actually do experience error pages...

Exception Notifier doesn't throw any email/notification for those errors but I am getting Amazon message alerts load balancer 500 errors. 

`AWS/ELB
 - MetricName:                 HTTPCode_Backend_5XX
 - Dimensions:                 [LoadBalancerName = xxx]`

Verdict ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these assets that you no longer have on your pages? If so - this can sometimes happen when eg google has cached an old copy of a page and then somebody (sometimes the google crawler) tries to look at it and fetch the assets from it... which no longer exists.

Normally you'd get a 404 for a missing asset, but in this case - Rails has changed the path with which you get to these assets, so it'll throw up a routing error as depicted.

Likewise - if you deploy a new version of your site and your asset has been updated (eg you added something to application.js)... the magic id for the asset changes... (the big long number) which causes the old version to no longer be available. The customer now needs to refresh their page to get the new URL for `application-<longmagicnumber>.js`

Comment: Alright, so most likely this isn't something very serious then... Is there some way to hint an expiration date for such cached pages ?

Comment: Rails is pretty smart about when to cache assets - if your asset changed (eg you've added a new js method) then you do want the user's browser to go fetch the new copy. So you don't want to mess with that... it's expiring at the correct time. That said, you probably really don't need to care whether the google-cache has a correct version of your js as it won't actually run js, few people look at the cached version and google will still try to look for it many years later. I'd say you can safely just ignore these.